# Java Code Integer Output

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code which raises 2 to

the powers of 0, 1, 2. 3. 4, .... n

For example for 31 it would  reproduce the following results:

```
  1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192
  16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152
  4194304 8388608 16777216 33554432 67108864 134217728
  268435456 536870912 1073741824 2147483648
```

I have written the following code:

```
public class Powersof2 {

  public static void printPowersOf2(int n) {
    if (n >= 0 && n <= 64) {
      for (int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++) {
        System.out.print( Math.pow(2, i) + "   ");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("You have input an invalid value");
      return;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     printPowersOf2(31);
     System.out.println();
  }
}
```

However, it produces the following result instead:

```
1.0   2.0   4.0   8.0   16.0   32.0   64.0   128.0   256.0   512.0
1024.0        2048.0   4096.0   8192.0   16384.0   32768.0   65536.0 
131072.0   262144.0        524288.0   1048576.0   2097152.0   4194304.0 
8388608.0   1.6777216E7       3.3554432E7   6.7108864E7   1.34217728E8 
2.68435456E8   5.36870912E8       1.073741824E9   2.147483648E9
```

How can I fix that?

**Also I have another question**

When I input larger values for n such as 62 the values start to be the same. For example 62 gives:

```
1   2   4   8   16   32   64   128   256   512   1024   2048   4096
8192   16384   32768   65536   131072   262144   524288   1048576  
2097152   4194304   8388608   16777216   33554432   67108864 134217728
268435456   536870912   1073741824   2147483647   2147483647    
2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   
2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647 
2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   
2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647 
2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647  
2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647   2147483647
```

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Since `int` has only of 32 bits, and its most significant bit is used for the sign, powers above 31 cannot be expressed in a Java `int`.

Comment: @dablinkenlight is there any way around that? make it 64 bit?

Comment: My answer lets you go up to 63 bits, because `1L` is `long`. 64-th bit is a sign bit, though, so in order to get beyond 63 you would need to use `BigInteger` - for example, like this: `BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I understand the concept of long but what is Biginteger?

Comment: [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is a class for representing arbitrarily large integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `public static double pow(double a, double b)` return a double. And Java `double` is 64 bit IEE754 number with precision, so you see the decimal points in the end.

You can cast it to `int` as `(int)Math.pow(2, i)`but **be aware** that for 2^31 onwards you will not get expected results because `int` range is from -2^31 to +2^31.

** First Solution:**
So, to get your expected result to get power up to 63, cast to `long` because Java `long` has range from -2^63 to +2^63

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 64; i++) {
            System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2, i));
        }
```

**You query about result as so many 2147483647** :
This is called as **Narrowing**, when a bigger container value is casted to smaller container value.

Below excerpt from [Java Language Specification - $5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), for rules governing primitive narrowing.

So, after power of 31, all the higher bits (32, 33....) are discarded, and hence you always result of 31 bits i.e. 2^31.

In you case, as per JLS, your "integral type T" was `int`, so all bits are discarded but the n lowest order bits (which means 31, because you are narrowing to `int`)

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.

**A comprehensive solution:** (as per discussion going around)
Primitive data types has range limitation, so there are BigInteger, BigDecimal which provides arbitrarily long values and precision. So, you can use `BigInteger` to get accurate result.

**Notice that** if you Java's long then for 2^63 you get result as `9223372036854775807` while as per [Power of two Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two) result should be `9223372036854775808` which you get when you use `BigInteger`

**Bottom line:** Use `BigInteger` to get desired range of power of 2.

Hope this covers all your concern and give you scalable solution.

```
       for (int i = 0; i <= 64; i++) {
            //System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2, i));
            System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i));  //Gives exact result as per Wiki information
        }
```

Comment: can you give the question a second view. I added a thing. @hagrawal

Comment: @JackStew Added, have a look. Please let me know in case of any question. Please do read JLS for narrowing rules.

Comment: @JackStew Check latest edit, I have tried to cover all your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Math.pow` returns a `double` while you are looking for an integer, consider using a simple bit trick for raising 2 to power `n` like this:

```
1L << n
```

The reason behind this trick is the same as that behind multiplying by powers of ten in the decimal system by writing additional zeros after the number.

This works for `n`s between 0 and 63, and produce a `long`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++) {
    System.out.print( (1L << i) + "   ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.pow()` always returns doubles. You need to cast it to an int. `System.out.print((int)Math.pow(2, i)+ "    ");`

Comment: Thanks, Are there any other ways to raise powers? @eagras

Comment: @JackStew  not any that i know of. I always use Math.pow

Answer (score 1):

These are the powers of `2` through 2^31, just in the default output format of a `double`.  With lower values, it will append `.0`, and with higher values, it's in pseudo-scientific notation.  E.g. `1.6777216E7` means 1.677216 x 10<sup>7</sup>, or 1,677,216.  The `double` is returned from `Math.pow`.

You may find an integer type data type better formatted for your purpose.  Use `long`, because `int` isn't quite big enough to store 2^31.

```
long product = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++)
{
    System.out.print( product + "   ");
    product *= 2;  // Equivalent: product <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: can I give the question a second view. I added a second part. @rgettman

Comment: If you were to cast the `double` to an `int`, and if the value is larger than the largest possible `int`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is 2^31 - 1 (`2147483647`), then the value is narrowed to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  You could cast to `long`, or you could keep the product as a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

i could have used below code part, instead math.pow() , i am always scared of type conversion

```
int num=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(num);
        num=num*2;
    }
```

but as suggested it can not go beyond 31 . it is limit of int data type. try BigInteger if you want to print more

Comment: Yeah but it isn't number times 2 it is 2 raised to number @Bhupi

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can simply use the following stream:

```
IntStream.range(0, 32)
    .map(value -> 1 << value)
    .forEach(value -> System.out.println("value = " + value));
```

Also, the same is applicable to `LongStream`.